# Twilio receive sms asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twilio

I want to be able to send an sms using Twilio and then if the receiver of the message responds to the sms it will take the body of the message and save it into my database. I can send an sms from my application. My question is how do I receive the response. I know how to insert the response into the database.

Also, the sms is sent from a specific project with a unique id. I want to be able to somehow tag the message so when they reply back I can insert their reply back and reference it back to that project.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

There is unfortunately no way to insert metadata into a SMS message.  You can however use the Twilio phone number you are [sending the message from](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) as a unique identifier. When your user replies, check the From parameter passed by Twilio as part of its POST request to see how to associate the incoming message with your applications data.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not an optimal way to do this, but through the REST api could I just set message url?  I could then include the parameters in a query string so when they reply to the message I could then add it to the database with the correct parameters? The downside of doing this would be if you have multiple sms going out for different projects it wouldn't work.

Comment: You certainly can change the Message URL via the REST API, but as you mention that technique comes with its own problems.  If you have multiple projects, you could purchase a seperate phone number for each and use that as the unique identifier.  You could combine the two techniques and recycle a phone number to a new project once an existing project finishes.

Answer (score 0):

To store the incoming message - You have to configure a message URL on this `https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/incoming` page. When your twilio number receives a message , twilio sends POST parameters to the message URL. On the message URL you can write a code to store the parameters on the database.

Comment: I know how to do that. My problem is I want to be able to some how code the message url with a parameter that ties that message to a specific project. When they reply to that message I then can grab post parameter body of the reply message and add that as a note into my database and reference the project it is associated with. The projectID in the database.

Comment: The sender and the receiver are using the same app to communicate?